# How to change bottom margin of swipeRefreshlayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, margins

I have such layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".jobAGENT.JobsList">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/no_jobs"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_t"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/job_list_t"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to change margin of RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout programmatically when I reach some conditions. For example, at my `onScrollListener` when my list reaches its end I would like to change bottom margin of my views and show progressbar below it. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411634/set-runtime-margin-to-any-view-using-kotlin) questions and I have also managed to change margin of refreshLayout but the last item of RV become cut and I think that I have to change margin of RV also. But I can't get layout params of this view. For refreshLayout I used smth like that:

```
val param = refreshLayout.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
param.setMargins(5,10,5,150)
refreshLayout.layoutParams = param
```

and it works good, but how I can also change margin of recyclerview which is placed inside refresh layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    params.setMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
    jobListT.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 4):

Last item in your `RecyclerView` cuts, meaning, you'll have to add padding only to the last element of `RecyclerView`, instead of giving padding to complete `RecyclerView`.

You can do that by setting `android:clipToPadding="false`", and giving it `paddingBottom` equal to the height of your `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

You can do that as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Adjust the `paddingBottom` as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion, instead add the progress bar as an item of the recyclerview at the last position when you reach the scroll end... this will ensure that the bar is displayed.. It is easy enough to have multiple types of viewholders in a recyclerview and this should solve your issue without needing to add any margin/padding

Comment: I don't add the progress bar as an item of the recyclerview