# How to set the margins in TextInputEditText programmatically in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How do I set the margins of my TextInputEditText programmatically in Kotlin in a AlertDialogBuilder?

```
val input = TextInputEditText(context!!)
            input.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            CommonHelper.capitalizeTextbox(input)
            input.inputType =
                InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            input.setSingleLine()
            input.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

            val lp: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )

            input.layoutParams = lp
            setMargins(input, 50,10,50,10)
            alertDialog.setView(input)
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_plate)


private fun setMargins(view: View, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
    if (view.layoutParams is MarginLayoutParams) {
        val p = view.layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams
        p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
        view.layoutParams = p
        view.invalidate()
    }
}
```

I tried `lp.setMargins(50, 10, 50, 10)` but it doesn't work too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50765990/9523118 Check this it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the correct approach by setting the margin on the `layoutParams`. The miss here is that you have to apply the layout params back to the `view` and call `invalidate()`.

So your `setMargins` function code should look like below:

```
private fun setMargins(view: View, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
    if (view.layoutParams is ViewGroup.LayoutParams) {
        val p = view.layoutParams
        p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
        // Set the layout params back to the view
        view.layoutParams = p
        // Call invalidate to redraw the view
        view.invalidate()
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The if check for `MarginLayoutParams` instance check won't be satisfied because your params are of the `LinearLayoutParams` type.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir. But still it doesn't work. I still cannot see the margins. The inputbox is still occupying the whole dialog builder. Please see my edit.

Comment: Sir I checked the code. You are doing a MarginLayoutParams instance check which won't satisfy because it will be of the LinearLayoutParams or ViewGroup.LayoutParams type of instance.

Comment: Please check the updated code. I changed the instance check and the first statement inside the if block. Please try this, it should work.